# IntelliJ stopped responding and after restarting, it throws "Start Failed - Internal error" and I cannot start it again

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Cool. Per my observation, IntelliJ IDEA has been getting slower and slower, more and more buggy, as the time passed. Now it got freezed during development process (a simple Hibernate maven project) and when I killed the process (IntelliJ IDEA) and attempted to start a it over, I got this:

[image]

..and now it's showing up again and again.. as many times, as I unsuccessfully try to run the IDE. [This](https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors) does not help.

What has been done with this IDE, seriously?

Please, note, that I'm well aware, that uploading pictures are not the best thing we can do here, but sometimes there is no better way do demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Did you check troubleshooting page suggested in the error popup? https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

Comment: @ocos of course.

Comment: Sorry to hear that troubleshooting page did not solve your problem. I would try a clean install with `Intellij IDEA` and/or `IDEA Community Edition`.

Comment: Please contact IDEA support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the [logs folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

Comment: As a workaround you can try to backup and delete the [system](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory) and [plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#plugins-directory) directories and reinstall from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download